# Where is differential drive repository?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Referenced repository does not seem to exist.

```
    http://wiki.ros.org/differential_drive

Source: git https://jfstepha@code.google.com/p/differential-drive/
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/97741/where-is-differential-drive-repository?/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There appears to be an active repository at that location. The clone URL is https://code.google.com/p/differential-drive/ (which you can find going to Source -> Checkout).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1